# Running PHP on IIS - file permissions are correct but uploads don't work

Tags: php, iis, permissions

I'm moving a wordpress instalation from XAMPP to an IIS server running PHP and running into this.

My file permissions are set to this for both Plesk Users, as instructed by the hosting company (i asked for permissions equivalent to chmod 755):
[image: File Permissions]

This is not working for any file/plugin uploads though. And i'm met with this error everytime:

> Warning: touch() [function.touch]: Unable to create file
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\zzzzz.com\httpdocs\oly/wp-content/slide1.tmp
>   because Permission denied in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\zzzzz.com\httpdocs\oly\wp-admin\includes\file.php
>   on line 177

I've checked and my php.ini seems to be ok regarding `file_uploads` (on), `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` (20M each). Also `safe_mode` is off.

How can i go about solving this?

Comment: You have `...\httpdocs\oly/wp-content/slide1.tmp` in the error message but the screenshot shows settings for `.../httpdocs/.../wp-content/uploads` -- a subfolder. What are the permissions for the _folder you're using_?

Comment: !damn... i've never had to deal with permissions on that folder, but it turns out it had NO PERMISSIONS whatsoever, for some obscure reason. Problem solved! Please move your comment to an answer so i can accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP appears to complain about writing in `C:\Inetpub\vhosts\zzzzz.com\httpdocs\...\wp-content/` directory where as the screenshot shows settings for `...\httpdocs\...\wp-content/uploads` which is a subfolder.

Check the permissions of the folder where files are being written. Looking at the screenshot, I can guess that the parent directory does not have the permissions set for IIS anonymous user/worker processes.